# Регистрация пользователя. Занесение данных в БД. В чем проблема?

Tags: php

```
<?php
require("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$password = $_POST['password'];
$rpassword = $_POST['rpassword'];

if($password == $rpassword)
{
    $fname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
    $lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
    $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $mail = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users'     ('id','first_name','last_name','username','email','password') VALUES (NULL, '$fname','$lname','$uname','$mail','$pass')");
}
else
{
    echo "Your passwords must match!";
    exit();
}
}
else
{
echo '
<form action="register.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="rpassword"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Out" name="submit"><br>
</form>';
}
?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста! Уже долгое время как мучаюсь я над тем как зарегистрировать пользователя, и занести его данные в БД, смотрю видеоуроки, читаю, но опять же на практике не получается. Помогите мне разобраться, в чем проблема тут? Что не так делаю? Очень буду благодарен! Заранее, спасибо!

Вот и config.php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("registr");
?>
```

Comment: На каком этапе сбой? Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Никакую. Нажимаю на кнопку, появляется белая страница с тем же урл. Захожу в БД, а там пусто :/

Comment: Включите отображение всех ошибок и еще раз проверьте:

    <?
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ?>

Comment: Ничего не выводится абсолютно! Вот открываю страницу, там формы. Заполняю все данные, нажимаю на кнопку и страница очищается! Страница пустая, а в БД ничего нет. Пусто. Не понимаю сам

Comment: Тьфу ты... Уберите кавычки с названия таблицы. ))

Comment: Увы :( тоже пустота царствует в БД

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users'    
 ('id','first_name','last_name','username','email','password') VALUES 
 (NULL, '".$fname."','".$lname."','".$uname."','".$mail."','".$pass."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Ведь не так сложно сделать кавычки!

**//upd**

Скопируй этот запрос полностью отсюда что скажет мускул на это.

```
$res=mysql_query("
INSERT INTO  `users` (
`id` ,
`first_name` ,
`last_name` ,
`username` ,
`email`  ,
`password` ,
)
VALUES (NULL, '".$fname."','".$lname."','".$uname."','".$mail."','".$pass."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Да ну и без конкатенации должно работать. Там где-то собачка зарыта глубже.

Comment: or die(mysql_error()); и строку добавить и ошибку в вопрос запостить, тоже не так сложно!

Comment: Дело не в кавычках. Понимаете, он абсолютно ничего не выводит! Не знаю зачем! Ваши кавычки тоже не дали результат

Comment: @navi1893 вы слепы или немного туго соображаете?

**or die(mysql_error()); ** для чего написано?

Comment: да, спасибо! Вот эррор: ﻿You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' ('id','first_name','last_name','username','email','password') VALUES (NU' at line 1

Comment: отлично что в 8 строке написано? Ну можно комменты развернутые писать, что выпрашивать данные каждый раз чтоли?

//upd

попробуй в конце **.$pass."')")** изменить на **.$pass."');")**

Comment: о! Вуаля! У тебя там в конце лишняя запятая была, я его удалил и он добавил в БД пользователя! Спасибо!

Comment: я узнал в чем проблема, я вместо `id` писал 'id'. Вся проблема в кавычках была!

Comment: С каких это пор "INSERT" возвращает результат? (хоть это и не поможет)

Comment: @mccrush Вы как вообще в mySql дружите?

> функция mysql_query () возвращают результат, 

**false или true** в случае успешности запроса, любого запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, поле `id` автоинкремент 
тогда из запроса

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'users'     ('id','first_name','last_name','username','email','password') VALUES (NULL, '$fname','$lname','$uname','$mail','$pass')");
```

попробуй убрать поле `id` и сделать вот так

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users`     (first_name,last_name,'username,email, password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$uname','$mail','$pass')");
```

Comment: Безрезультатно :( в чем проблема?! Этой ситуацией я уже долгое время сталкиваюсь и никак решать не могу!(

Answer (score 0):

```
'username,
```

зачем перед ним кавычка то?
Скиньте лучше дамп структуры базы данных. Чувствую, там копать нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`first_name`,`last_name`,`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$uname','$mail','$pass')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Следи за кавычками!

Answer (score 0):

Во первых вы не составили переменную в config.php которая имеет подключение к бд. Потом эту переменную вставить в начале запроса mysql_query . И еще в mysql_escape_string попробуйте тоже вставлять переменную с подключением к бд. И да, может mysqli_query? mysqli_escape_string? (Я рассказываю свой робочий метод). И зачем перечислять id? я его не перпечисляю

Comment: Извините, у вас много вопросителэных знаков. Вы не уверены в своём  ответе?